# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react native metro builder

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I get that problem after the app have successfuly run on my device. I don't understand whats the problem. Here is the error

```
 bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at resolveDependencies (D:\Projects\twitterBot\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
at D:\Projects\twitterBot\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\Projects\twitterBot\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
at _next (D:\Projects\twitterBot\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:107:9)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: What it says, you are trying to iterate with map() on an undefined variable.

Comment: No, I have just created the project. The error comes from node modules.

Comment: which dependencies do you have?

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing an undefined variable to a dependency? maybe post some relevant code of where you are implementing `twitterBot` as that may be the issue

Comment: Yes,  I am sure. But I got the error was temp folder. Which I then deleted all contents

Answer (score 8):

The solution is  deleting contents of `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp` folder.

Comment: I solved this issue my deleting this folder C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\metro-cache

Comment: Really Worked. Thanks bro.